# Web Plugin for 2.14.9 Essen

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I last used QGIS 2.14.9 Essen in September 2018 with no problems. Today 28/11/18 I tried to open Google Maps plugin (and Bing maps etc.) but I am getting the following error message - `OpenLayers Plugin: Printing and rotating of JavaScript API based layers is currently not supported`

I have reinstalled the Open Layers plugin to no avail.

Comment: Why don't you update to 2.18 or even 3.4, the newer LTRs?

Answer (score 2):

Try [QuickMapServices plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/). This is featured QGIS plugin and good replacement for OpenLayers plugin.